# CompletedSubTask' object has no attribute 'aspect_representation

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working on an aspect based sentiment.
I am just trying to get the code to work which is in example on the module blog.
but i have this error:

```
html = absa.probing.explain(slack)
display(html)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-98b6fe874b12> in <module>
----> 1 html = absa.probing.explain(slack)
      2 display(html)

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/aspect_based_sentiment_analysis/probing/plots.py in explain(example)
     47 
     48 def explain(example: PredictedExample):
---> 49     aspect = example.aspect_representation
     50     texts = [f'Words connected with the "{example.aspect}" aspect: <br>']
     51     texts.extend(highlight_sequence(aspect.tokens, aspect.look_at))

AttributeError: 'CompletedSubTask' object has no attribute 'aspect_representation'
```

Here more : https://pypi.org/project/aspect-based-sentiment-analysis/

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: yes, thanks. Can you help me with the other issue?

Comment: please share the solution for me and others

Comment: yeah @kyrion how did you fix it